# odoo 16 adding custom module

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo-16

I have try to add the already written module into my odoo 16 but i dont know why its giving this error i am new to odoo.
i just install and config the odoo16 in pycharm and then download the custom module from github and copy it in the addon folder the module is showing in the apps but i can not able to active it its giving me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 1584, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "D:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\service\model.py", line 134, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "D:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 1613, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "D:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 1810, in dispatch
    result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "D:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 149, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
  File "D:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\http.py", line 699, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "d:\odoo\odoo-16.0\addons\web\controllers\dataset.py", line 46, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "d:\odoo\odoo-16.0\addons\web\controllers\dataset.py", line 33, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "D:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\api.py", line 461, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "D:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\api.py", line 448, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-74>", line 2, in button_immediate_install
  File "D:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 76, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 491, in button_immediate_install
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_install)
  File "D:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 615, in _button_immediate_function
    registry = modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "<decorator-gen-14>", line 2, in new
  File "D:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\tools\func.py", line 87, in locked
    return func(inst, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 90, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "D:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 487, in load_modules
    processed_modules += load_marked_modules(cr, graph,
  File "D:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 371, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(
  File "D:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 196, in load_module_graph
    model_names = registry.load(cr, package)
  File "D:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 247, in load
    model = cls._build_model(self, cr)
  File "D:\odoo\odoo-16.0\odoo\models.py", line 615, in _build_model
    raise TypeError("Model %r does not exist in registry." % name)
TypeError: Model 'stock.production.lot' does not exist in registry.
```

for extra information i am using latest ver of pycharm+odoo16+python 3.10.9
this is the module i  am trying to add
https://github.com/odoo-ps/psae-btco/tree/sally-flower-shop/flower_shop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the code source, you will find that `stock_production_lot.py` file was removed and replaced with `stock_lot.py`

Update your code and rename `stock.production.lot` to `stock.lot`

Comment: it worked it just need some code adjustments where ever the stock.production.lot is used in the whole module with stock.lot